# How can i Search from INNER JOIN tables through Employee ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i created two tables 
1: Employee_Personal_Info and 2: Compensation. i gave them relationship with EPI_NO(employee ID). when i implement this Query

```
$sql_search = "Select * FROM Employee_Personal_Info
INNER JOIN Compensation ON Employee_Personal_Info.EPI_NO=Compensation.EPI_NO;"
or die (sql_error);
```

it works fine and shows all records. Now i want to search an specific employee through a submit button by giving its EPI_NO id.

```
<form action="" method="get">
Search From Database <input type="text" name="searchdata"/> </br>
<input type="submit" value="Employee Personal and Contact Info" name="info" /> </form>
```

Plz help me .

Comment: Are you trying to get the `SELECT... FROM... INNER JOIN... WHERE` query written for you, or the markup? or both? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [WHERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) statement

```
$sql_search = "Select * FROM Employee_Personal_Info
INNER JOIN Compensation ON Employee_Personal_Info.EPI_NO=Compensation.EPI_NO
WHERE Employee_Personal_Info.EPI_NO = 1;"
or die (sql_error);
```

In this case `1` is the employee ID you are looking for.

To integrate this with your code, you need to [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) your query.

This is an example, using the code from the above documentation.

```
$id = $_POST['searchdata'];

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select * FROM Employee_Personal_Info
INNER JOIN Compensation ON Employee_Personal_Info.EPI_NO=Compensation.EPI_NO
WHERE Employee_Personal_Info.EPI_NO = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($employee);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy.. i have another Question, i have another database created on Microsoft Access. when i run your given code it gives error. 
 Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in F:\DreamWeaver\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: That code is PHP. The SQL itself should work. I don't know access all that well, but you need to substitute the `?` with your value and that query should work for you in access

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

$sql_search = "Select * FROM Employee_Personal_Info
INNER JOIN Compensation ON Employee_Personal_Info.EPI_NO=Compensation.EPI_NO AND Employee_Personal_Info.EPI_NO = ".$_GET['searchdata'].";"

Comment: But in the form method is used as "GET", <form action="" method="get">
Search From Database <input type="text" name="searchdata"/> </br>
<input type="submit" value="Employee Personal and Contact Info" name="info" /> </form>

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can add the WHERE statemen

```
<?

$sql_search = "Select * FROM Employee_Personal_Info
INNER JOIN Compensation ON Employee_Personal_Info.EPI_NO=Compensation.EPI_NO;" or die (sql_error);

if(isset($_POST['searchdata']))
{
  $sql_search = $sql_search."  WHERE ".$_POST['searchdata'];
}

?>
```

in this case, you are using get in form, so you can request it in if clause with $_GET['searchdata']

Comment: Please don't show a new programmer the wrong way to write a query. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Instead, they should use a [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) statement